# Stripe connect subscription with direct payments and checkout form

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm making a multiparty system where users will be able to subscribe to services from third parties using direct payment and checkout form. I found scattered documentation on various pieces:

This [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions#direct) operates with some product and price id. According to their product and price API it's unclear if it's possible to create a product and price in connected account. Where in general can I obtain a price id in multiparty system?

This [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout#create-session) operates also with price id, but on of that it's unclear if it's possible to create a session with connected account rather than our own.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can create subscription on the connected account. Take a look at https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/connect

Comment: Yes, I saw that documentation, but it asks for price, which is supposed to be defined in dashboard. Is it possible to create product and price in *connected* account (I don't see it possible in API)?

Comment: it is possible. e.g. You can create product in your platform account like this 
`curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/products  -u sk_test_uxfxxxxL:  -d name="Gold Special"`. To create the product in connected account, you just add the Stripe account header like 
`curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/products  -u sk_test_uxfxxxxL:  -d name="Gold Special" -H "Stripe-Account: acct_xxxxxx"`